# How to use if statement along with case in sql server

Tags: sql

i have few columns in my source table (CountryCodes, SubCodes) and the values for those columns are

```
Subcodes   CountryCodes  
100         1111
100         1566
100         2485
100         4586
101         4789
101         4756
101         7895     so on
```

i am using below query which is giving me results as per required

```
select 
    CASE  WHEN C.SubCodes= '100' Then 
            CASE 
                WHEN C.CountryCodes IN ('5001','5048') THEN '001'
                WHEN C.CountryCodes = '5005' THEN '003'
                WHEN C.CountryCodes= '5018' AND SA.Amt IN(30,900) THEN '094'
                WHEN C.CountryCodes = '5018' AND SA.Amt IN(40,1200) THEN '095'
                WHEN C.CountryCodes = '5018' AND SA.Amt IN(50,1500) THEN '096'
                WHEN C.C.CountryCodes  = '5029' THEN '781'
                WHEN C.C.CountryCodes  = '5026' THEN '454'
                WHEN C.C.CountryCodes  = '5064' THEN '001'
                WHEN C.C.CountryCodes  = '5017' THEN '064' 
                               ELSE CAST('' AS CHAR(3))
            END 
    ELSE CAST('' AS CHAR(3))    
END
        END AS SomeCountryCoDes
```

now business has given new requirement. That is

CountryCode 5020 resides in SubCode 100.

Now my requirement is if `CountryCode 5020` is in `Subcode 100` then i need to change the value of subCode from 100 to 101.

the above case statement has to be ammended with if statement.

Step1: If CountryCode = 5020 and subcode= 100 then Subcode has to be 101  Else case statement

Step2: Above mentioned Case statement has to be followed after IF

Note: in Source table the value shouldn't be chnaged.

Comment: You cannot use an IF statement inside a SELECT.
Maybe your problem could be solved with a trigger. Make a trigger that checks for your requirements and apply the changes necessary.

Comment: on this line `WHEN C.CountryCodes  = '5020' THEN '000'` why not use `100` instead of `000`?

Comment: why you cannot change value in table? If you dont change value then how will your case statement work

Comment: Can you show the `complete CASE` you have written so far, there may be an easy way to nest it.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do just one case instead of nesting cases:

```
CASE WHEN C.SubCode = '100' AND C.CountryCode in ('5001', '5048') THEN '001'
  WHEN C.SubCode = '100' AND C.CountCode =- '5005' THEN '003'
  ...
  WHEN C.SubCode = '100' AND CountryCode = '5020' THEN '101'
  ...
END
```

Comment: the value will be assigned as 101 but it will not loop with condition